# How to display different prefabs with Image tracking in ARfoundation with Unity?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am using a dictionary to save instantiated prefab along with the image name.So when ever the corresponding image comes the matching prefab is shown.I am able to display prefabs with different images but the issue is I want to hide the prefab when the images is not being tracked and also unhide when the image is retracked.When the image gets added the prefab gets instantiated.

```
public void OnImageChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs args)
{
    //For everytime an image gets detected a video is played.Runs only when image is added
    foreach (var trackedImage in args.added)
    {
        Debug.Log("Instantiate Cube");
        cubePrefab = Instantiate(cubeTv, trackedImage.transform);
        //Getting file name of the video 
        var data = allDataContent.FirstOrDefault(i => i.imgFileName == trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
        videoName = data.vidFileName;

        //Getting the videoplayer component from he instantiated gameobject
        vp = cubePrefab.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        vp.source = VideoSource.Url;
        vp.url = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + videoName;

        vp.playOnAwake = true;
        vp.isLooping = true;
        vp.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.MaterialOverride;
        vp.targetMaterialRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        vp.targetMaterialProperty = "_MainTex";
        vp.Play();

        //Adding the prefab and name to a dictionary    
        holdList.Add(cubePrefab, trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
    }

    foreach (var trackedImage in args.updated)
    {
        if (trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
        {
            //Getting the video with respect to the tracked image
            var data = allDataContent.FirstOrDefault(i => i.imgFileName == trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
            videoName = data.vidFileName;
            if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + videoName))
            {
                foreach (var v in holdList.Values)
                {
                    //Getting the correct gameobject from the dictionary according to tracked image
                    GameObject go = holdList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == trackedImage.referenceImage.name).Key;
                    if (v == trackedImage.referenceImage.name)
                    {
                        go.SetActive(true);

                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // go.SetActive(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // cubePrefab.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    foreach (var trackedImage in args.removed)
    {
       //Read in some forum this is not working
    }
}
```

Bit confused about what is happening in the `foreach (var trackedImage in args.updated)`.

EDIT:- Unity AndroidVideoMedia: Error -10000 while starting codec.When I uncomment `go.SetActive(false);` When I show the device camera to first image it the prefab instantiates and plays the video after shown to the second image the prefab instantiates but the video is not playing.

Comment: what exactly is the question? Do you have any specific issue/error? Or do you just want someone to tell you what your code does?

Comment: @derHugo Edited.When I show to the first image the prefab comes and plays the vid then after showing it to the second image the prefab comes but video not playing when I uncomment the `go.SetActive(false);`

Comment: well maybe because you already `continue;` in the first case?

Comment: I commented the `continue;` and uncommented `go.SetActive(false);` from the else part.I show the device camera to the first image the video plays and show the camera to the second image the prefab comes but the video not playing after few seconds crashes with AndroidVideoMedia: Error -10000 while starting codec and AndroidVideoMedia: Decoder setup error.

Comment: @derHugo Will the video take time to load? Is that the reason for crash? If I wait for 2 sec and showthe device camera to the image the video plays.If I change images quickly it will crash.My guess is that foreach statement is running in `args.updated` is causing this issue.My answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the `foreach (var trackedImage in args.added)` loop run only one time when a new image which is already added in the library is detected.There I am instantiating the prefab.I add the instantiated prefab to the dictionary along with the detected image name.So whenever the image is shown again I can hide and unhide prefabs according to the image detected.

```
 public void OnImageChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs args)
{

    foreach (var trackedImage in args.added)
    {
       //Instantiating prefab
        cubePrefab = Instantiate(cubeTv, trackedImage.transform);
        Debug.Log("Cube prefb name "+cubePrefab.name);
        var data = allDataContent.FirstOrDefault(i => i.imgFileName == trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
        videoName = data.vidFileName;
        Debug.Log("Video File Name = " + videoName);
        vp = cubePrefab.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        vp.source = VideoSource.Url;
        vp.url = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + videoName;

        vp.playOnAwake = true;
        vp.isLooping = true;
        vp.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.MaterialOverride;
        vp.targetMaterialRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        vp.targetMaterialProperty = "_MainTex";
        vp.Play();


        holdList.Add(cubePrefab, trackedImage.referenceImage.name);


    }
    foreach (var trackedImage in args.updated)
    {


        if (trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking)
        {


            var data = allDataContent.FirstOrDefault(i => i.imgFileName == trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
            videoName = data.vidFileName;
            if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + videoName))
            {

                foreach (var v in holdList.Values)
                {
                    go = holdList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == trackedImage.referenceImage.name).Key;
                    if (v == trackedImage.referenceImage.name)
                    {

                        go.SetActive(true);


                    }
                    else if(v!= trackedImage.referenceImage.name)
                    {


                         List<GameObject> go = new List<GameObject>();
                         var exceptOne = holdList.Where(i => i.Value != trackedImage.referenceImage.name).ToList();
                         foreach (var item in exceptOne)
                         {
                             go.Add(item.Key);
                         }
                         foreach (var gameObjectone in go)
                         {
                             gameObjectone.SetActive(false);
                         }

                    }
                }



            }




            }
        else
        {

           // go.SetActive(false);
        }




    }

    foreach (var trackedImage in args.removed)
    {
       // go.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

The issue I faced is when changing the images quickly it crashes otherwise it video plays.Any other solutions are welcome